# ACPI BIOS Error(bug) with file lost

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd, acpi

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 but recently faced weird problem.

After complete shutdown, next day after start sometime got this error.

[image]

Then manually invoking `fsck /dev/sdb2` solve the problem but every time there was missing something or some file.  One occurrence I found that my `home` was deleted. Another time some binary was missing.

I did a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation that also didn't help either.

I suspect that my SSD may be corrupted but according to `smartctl -a` it's OK.

Configuration:

```
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
SSD: ADATA SU650 (V8X01b10)
HDD: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 (AX1R4C)
```

Ubuntu installed on SSD (sdb2)